# Select records that start with special letter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Imagine that I have a table with several records like below:

```
zare
azre
arze
arez
```

I want to find records that contain `'z'` but if I search in these records first find `'zare'` because start with `'z'`, second find `'azre'` because `z` is second letter and etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE col LIKE '%z%'
ORDER BY CHARINDEX('z', col)
```

Comment: Nice answer @Hamlet Hakobyan +1